# Erro parse Json php

Tags: php, json

Tenho um erro ao montar um menu dinâmico com dados vindos do mysql.

Código que monta o menu:

```
<div class="easyui-accordion" data-options="multiple:true"  style="width:100%;">

  <?php
  $pdo = TConnection::open('teste');
  $sql = "select distinct a.IdMenu,a.descricao as Nome
        from Menu a inner join SubMenu b on b.IdMenu=a.IdMenu
        inner join Camada c on c.idCamada=b.IdCamada
        inner join CamadaOrganizacao d on d.IdCamada = c.IdCamada
        inner join CamadaUsuario e on e.IdCamada = c.IdCamada 
        where e.IdUsuario = ? order by a.descricao asc";
  $cat = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $cat->execute(array($user));
  if ($cat->rowCount() >= 1):
    echo '<div class="easyui-accordion" style="width:100%;">';

    foreach ($cat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $res) :
      $id = $res['IdMenu'];
      echo '<div title="' . $res['Nome'] . '" data-options="iconCls:\'icon-ok\'" style="overflow:auto;padding:0;">';

      $sql2 = "select IdSubMenu , '#principal' as abas,IdMenu, Descricao as Nome ,url from SubMenu  where IdMenu = ? order by Nome asc";
      $subMenu = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
      $subMenu->execute(array($id));

      if ($subMenu->rowCount() >= 1):
        echo '<ul class="easyui-datalist" title="" lines="true" style="width:100%;">';
        foreach ($subMenu->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $linha) :
          echo '<li>';
          echo '<a href ="#"  onclick="addTab('.$linha['abas'].','.$linha['Nome'] .','. $linha['url'] .');" >'. $linha['Nome'] .'</a>';
          //echo '<a href="#" onclick="addTab('.$linha['abas'].'","'.$linha['Nome'] . '","' . $linha['url'] . ')">' . $linha['Nome'] . '</a>';

          //echo '<a href="'.$linha['url'] . '">' . $linha['Nome'] . '</a>';
          echo '</li>';
        endforeach;
        echo '</ul>';
      endif;

      echo '</div>';
    endforeach;
    echo '</div>';
  endif;
  ?>
</div>
```

função javascript que abre á pagina em uma div.

```
function addTab(obj,title, url) {

  if ($(obj).tabs('exists', title)) {
    $(obj).tabs('select', title);
  } else {
    var hDiv = 0;
    hDiv = $("#MenuLateral").height();
    $(obj).height(hDiv);
    var content = '<iframe name="conteudo" id="conteudo" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"  src=' + url + ' style=""></iframe>';
    $(obj).tabs('add', {
      title: title,
      content: content,
      closable: true
    });
  };
};
```

Porém ao clicar no link da o seguinte erro, e não consegui identificar:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.
>   (function(event){addTab(#principal,Organizacao,./Organizacao.php); })

Alguém consegue me dar uma luz ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se abrires diretamente no browser a página `"../cliente/getMenu.php"` o que te aparece?

Comment: Qual é a necessidade de criar este menu via JS?

Comment: echo '<a href="#" onclick="addTab('.$linha['abas'] .','. $linha['Nome'] .', '.$linha['Url'] .')">'. $linha['Nome'] .'</a>';

Comment: Qual o erro? Adicione na pergunta.

Comment: Faltam aspas nos parâmetros da chamada `addTab`, o correto é algo assim: `echo "<a href =\"#\"  onclick=\"addTab('".$linha['abas']."','".$linha['Nome']."','".$linha['url']."');\" >". $linha['Nome'] ."</a>";`

Comment: Bacco, em primeiro lugar obrigado, Fiz as alterações como mencionou porém continua dando erro.

Comment: Bom, agora falta só algum ajuste, pq o erro já mudou mais pro final da linha. Se conseguisse colar um trecho do código gerado (usando o view-source do browser) fica mais fácil de vermos. E sempre cole como texto, nunca como imagem.

Comment: Ah, e tem algum caractere especial ali, talvez tenha que por um urlencode( ) em torno dos $linha[ ] para evitar isso: `addTab('".urlencode($linha['abas'])."` ou `addTab('".htmlentities($linha['abas'])."` em todos os campos (precisa ver como esses dados estão vindo, e qual a intenção na chamada pra ver qual é o mais adequado)

Comment: Bacco, mais uma vez  muiito obrigado, valeu mesmo......, consegui resolver reescrivi a linha novamente e funcionou.